# Navigation using Assemble

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

### Part I

I created a 'static' navigation in my handlebar file for the header (header.hbs - below). I'd like to create this simple, one-level navigation using handlebars (which I'm new too currently). Also would like to add an "active" class based on the page the user is on.

```
<nav class="left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html" title="Products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="find-us.html" title="Find Us">Find Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

### Part II

I was able to get this working (see answer below). How does one achieve sort-order? Right now the links seem to be in random order.

Comment: sort order can be a tricky beast, partially because of handlebars, but mostly because of how we're handling context in assemble v0.4.0. My suggestion is that you mark this as answered and open a new question for that so you can get more feedback

Comment: Seems I can only post every 90 minutes on SO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have RTFM :)

There's a whole section in the FAQ for this exact thing, ha! Go figure.

```
{{#each pages }}
  {{#is data.section "main"}}
    <li{{#is ../../page.dest this.dest}} class="active"{{/is}}>
        <a href="{{relative ../../page.dest this.dest}}">{{data.menutitle}}</a>
    </li>
  {{/is}}
{{/each}}
```

http://assemble.io/docs/FAQ.html